# How to use ViewPager + Fragment +ListView

Tags: android

[image]
  [image]

here is my Code,the `Activity`is to show 7 tabs from Mon. to Sun.each tabs use the same `fragment`,I wanna add a `ListView` to load the imformation,but I don't how to do

Activity:

```
package space.levan.myclass.activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTab;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabListener;
import space.levan.myclass.R;
import space.levan.myclass.fragment.LessonFragment;
import space.levan.myclass.utils.InfoUtil;
import space.levan.myclass.utils.NetUtil;

/**
 * Created by 339 on 2016/5/3.
 */
public class ScheduleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     MaterialTabListener{
@Bind(R.id.materialTabHost)
MaterialTabHost mTabHost;
@Bind(R.id.pager)
ViewPager mViewPager;

ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

private List<HashMap<String, Object>> ClassInfos;
private HashMap<String, Object> ClassInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setTitle("课程表");
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Fragment lessonFragment;

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // when user do a swipe the selected tab change
            mTabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

        }
    });

    // insert all tabs from pagerAdapter data
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTab()
                        .setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this)
        );

    }

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int temp = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 2;
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(temp);

    Map<String, String> loginInfo = InfoUtil.getLoginInfo(ScheduleActivity.this);
    getLesson(loginInfo.get("StuToken"));
}

public String getLesson(final String mToken) {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            String result = NetUtil.getSchedule(mToken);
            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    int error = jsonObject.getInt("error");
                    String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                    switch (error) {
                        case 0:
                            getDes(jsonObject);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            showToast(message);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            reLogin();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                showToast("数据异常");
            }
        }
    }.start();

    return null;
}

private void getDes(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    try {
        JSONObject Object = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONObject data = Object.getJSONObject("data");
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            JSONObject day = data.getJSONObject(""+i);
            for (int n = 1; n < 5; n++) {
                JSONArray lesson = day.getJSONArray(""+n);
                ClassInfos = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int m = 0; m < lesson.length();m++) {
                    JSONObject des = (JSONObject) lesson.get(m);
                    String name = des.getString("course");
                    String teacher = des.getString("teacher");
                    String time = des.getString("time");
                    String room = des.getString("classroom");

                    /*showToast("星期：" + i + "\n节次：" + n + "\n课程名字："
                            + name + "\n任课老师：" + teacher + "\n上课周数：" + time
                            + "\n教室：" + room);*/
                    ClassInfo = new HashMap<>();
                    ClassInfo.put("Name","课程名字：" + name);
                    ClassInfo.put("Teacher","上课老师：" + teacher);
                    ClassInfo.put("Time","上课周次：" + time);
                    ClassInfo.put("Room","上课教室：" + room);

                    ClassInfos.add(ClassInfo);
                }
            }

        }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void showToast(final String message) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(ScheduleActivity.this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void reLogin() {

    InfoUtil.deleteUserInfo(ScheduleActivity.this);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent intent = getPackageManager().
                    getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(ScheduleActivity.this,
                    "数据异常，请重新登录帐号",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {

}

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int num) {
        return new LessonFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        int temp = position+1;
        return "星期" + temp;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, R.string.home_about);
    return true;
}

/**
 * 用于界面返回按钮
 * @param item
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is fragment :

```
package space.levan.myclass.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by 339 on 2016/5/5.
 */
public class LessonFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView text = new TextView(container.getContext());
    text.setText("(╯°Д°)╯︵┴┴");
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a ListView in the LessonFragment.

Follow these steps:

1. Create a layout file with a listview.
2. Inflate this layout in onCreateView method of LessonFragment and  find this listview.
3. now, set an adapter for this listview, with the data you want.(hoping you know how to set an adapter)

   And now you have a listview in each tab.

   ```
   public class LessonFragment extends Fragment {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Bundle args = getArguments();

   }


   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(
               R.layout.fragment_lesson, container, false);
       mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

       //create an adapter 

       //set the above adapter to the listview


       return rootView;
   }
   }
   ```